# How to change text in customer dashboard sidebar?

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.3, customer-account, account

I need to change the **Address book** text to **My Contact Details** in customer dashboard sidebar links.

[image]

I used this below code but no use.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>       
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sidebar.main.account_nav" template="Magento_Theme::html/collapsible.phtml" before="-">

                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Contact Details</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/address</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">190</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>                
    </body>
</page>
```

In **customer_account.xml*.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead to modify your template for this label change just modify label by translations.
 create folder i18n in your custom theme in it create file en_US.csv and add translation into this file like following :

```
"Address book", "My Contact Details"
```

structure will be following:

[image]

Once you create this you can change every label in this way for whole site

Answer (score 2):

Just Copy This File In Your Theme `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/address.phtml`

**in This Path Paste address.phtml File**    `app/design/frontend/Theme/ThemeName/Magento_Customer/templates/account/dashboard`

In Line no. 13 Change Text As Per Your Requirement.

**After This Clean Cache and Test.**

---

> **Also Using Csv File Make Change This Title**

Create `{Your_LanagaugeCode}.csv` at if not exits

File Path :- **magento2/app/design/frontend/{themevendorname}/{Themename}/i18n/**)

**Then add below code at this csv file**

```
"Address book", "My Contact Details"
```

**Then do Cache flush and do the static content deploy.**